# Ping not working in network namespace

Tags: ubuntu, network-namespace

If I do:

```
sudo ip link add l4 type veth
sudo ip addr add "7.7.7.7/24" dev l4
ping 7.7.7.7
PING 7.7.7.7 (7.7.7.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 7.7.7.7: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.023 ms
64 bytes from 7.7.7.7: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.102 ms
```

ping is working

but in namespace:

```
sudo ip netns add test
sudo ip netns exec test ip link add l5 type veth
sudo ip netns exec test ip addr add "8.8.8.8/24" dev l5
sudo ip netns exec test ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2034ms
```

ping is failing.

Why this difference?

How to make ping work in namespace?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** the issue is not related to network namespaces, nor *veth* interfaces, but to the local routing between two local IPs going through the *lo* interface.

---

Here's a simplified version, not requiring a *veth* interface (nor any interface other than the loopback interface) to reproduce the problem:

```
# ip address add 192.0.2.2/32 dev lo
# ping -c2 192.0.2.2
PING 192.0.2.2 (192.0.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.0.2.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.162 ms
64 bytes from 192.0.2.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.108 ms

--- 192.0.2.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1061ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.108/0.135/0.162/0.027 ms

# ip netns add test
# ip -netns test address add 192.0.2.3/32 dev lo
# ip netns exec test ping -c2 192.0.2.3
PING 192.0.2.3 (192.0.2.3) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.0.2.3 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1027ms

# ip -netns test link set dev lo up
# ip netns exec test ping -c2 192.0.2.3
PING 192.0.2.3 (192.0.2.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.0.2.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
64 bytes from 192.0.2.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.069 ms

--- 192.0.2.3 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.037/0.053/0.069/0.016 ms
```

Choosing an entirely non-adequate interface (Intermediate Functional Block) will do the same:

```
# ip -netns test link set dev lo down # previous state
# ip -netns test link add name test0 type ifb
# ip -netns test address add 192.0.2.4/32 dev test0
# ip -netns test route get 192.0.2.4
local 192.0.2.4 dev lo src 192.0.2.4 uid 0 
    cache <local> 
# ip netns exec test ping -c2 192.0.2.4
PING 192.0.2.4 (192.0.2.4) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.0.2.4 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1006ms

# ip -netns test link set dev lo up
# ip netns exec test ping -c2 192.0.2.4
PING 192.0.2.4 (192.0.2.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.0.2.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.025 ms
64 bytes from 192.0.2.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms

--- 192.0.2.4 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1015ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.025/0.039/0.054/0.015 ms
```

The explanation is simple: By default when *any* IP assigned to *any* interface (even an entirely non-adequate interface, or also an interface in *down* state) tries to reach *any* same or other IP assigned to *any* same or other interface, with both IPs belonging to the same host, the route is using the *lo* interface, this goes along with the [weak host model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_Host_Model) used on Linux. It doesn't matter what the interface is intended for: it won't be used at all. **What matters is that the *lo* interface is up**. When a new network namespace is created, it's automatically receiving the *lo* interface, but in *down* state. For any local traffic to succeed in this network namespace, the *lo* interface has to be brought up.

Common misuse: assigning an IP to a tun/tap interface (the network packets, be they IP or anything else, must be handled by the application behind, not the kernel). While pinging the IP from the host will work as explaned above, this won't help solve any work and will hinder correct usage.

Now if the intended goal was to route between initial namespace and the test namespace, here's a working example with a pair of *veth* interfaces:

```
# ip link add name vethtotest0 type veth peer netns test name vethtoinit0
# ip link set dev vethtotest0 up
# ip -netns test link set dev vethtoinit0 up
# ip address add 198.51.100.1/24 dev vethtotest0
# ip -netns test address add 198.51.100.2/24 dev vethtoinit0
# ip netns exec test ping 198.51.100.1
# ip netns exec test ping -c2 198.51.100.1
PING 198.51.100.1 (198.51.100.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 198.51.100.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.171 ms
64 bytes from 198.51.100.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.101 ms

--- 198.51.100.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1055ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.101/0.136/0.171/0.035 ms
```

Still for the ping to 198.51.100.2 to succeed inside the test namespace, the *lo* interface must be up. It's not needed for the previous test since the route is through *vethtoinit0*.